# rxjs - How do you force observables to be called?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following that gets called on page load.

```
combineLatest([
      this.baseball.getPlayers(),
      this.baseball.getTeams(),
    ]).pipe(.....)
```

However, I emit from a child back to this parent and would like for this above code to be called again.  I'm guessing I have to use a subject but not sure how.  How do I do this?

```
emitCalled() {
     //call the above code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can use subject to trigger the above to be reevaluated

```
triggerSubject$ = new BehaviourSubject('');
myObservable$ = combineLatest([
  this.baseball.getPlayers(),
  this.baseball.getTeams(),
]).pipe(.....)
myUpdatedObservable$ = this.triggerSubject$.asObservable().pipe(
  mergeMap(() => this.myObservable$)
)
```

And where you would want the observable to be reevaluated

```
emitCalled() {
   this.triggerSubject$.next(null)
}
```

in your html

```
<ng-container *ngIf='myUpdatedObservable$ | async as myUpdatedObservable'>
  // myUpdatedObservable will contain the updated result here
</ng-container>
```

NB: I am using `BehaviourSubject` to ensure that the observable evaluated when the app loads

Comment: This worked. However, any ideas why my view is not updating after the emit?  The console shows new results and I’m using a sync pipe in the view.

Comment: You need to subscribe to the updated observable. I have updated the solution

Answer (score 1):

You're right about using a subject, try this:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

emitSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
.....
combineLatest([
      this.baseball.getPlayers(),
      this.baseball.getTeams(),
      this.emitSubject.asObservable(),
    ]).pipe(.....)

emitCalled() {
     this.emitSubject.next(null);
}
```

Something like that should work. I am on my mobile so I may have made mistakes.

======= Edit ========

To make fresh API calls every time emit is called, you will need to use `switchMap`.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

emitSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
.....
// emitSubject is the initiation of the chain
this.emitSubject.asObservable().pipe(
  // switch to this observable every time emit subject gets a new value
  switchMap(_ => combineLatest([
      this.baseball.getPlayers(),
      this.baseball.getTeams(),
    ])),
).pipe(........)


emitCalled() {
     this.emitSubject.next(null);
}
```

Comment: I don't see my API calls being made on the emit.

Comment: I have made an edit, that should hopefully work for you.